# Best practice to check if a user is allowed to update a row

Tags: java, stored-procedures, spring-jdbc

I am writing a REST API that performs an update. I am using SpringJDBC in my Java code, and stored procedures in the back end.

But before that update is performed, I need to check some conditions:

- if the user is in the correct group (this info is from a service call, and not from Spring security)
- if the row the user is going to
  update has some characteristics
- etc

The actual update is done by a stored procedure. What is the best approach to this?

- Should I perform a select, get the info on that row and then perform the update if the info is OK?
- Or should I just send all the info to the stored procedure and let it handle if the row should be updated or not?

EDIT: Spring security is not an option, sadly

Comment: Depends on the stored procedure is capable of performing all checkings required or not.

Comment: depends where you wish to handle verification..  in the sql server, or on your application server (if they're the same this whole question is irrelevant) depending how complicated the process is, if it's resource hogging to verify each user, let the balance fall on the less "busy" box, if it's not, then this really isn't an issue.

Comment: if you are already using spring, then you shouldn't have issues with pulling spring security. with spring security, you could put annotation on each method with required roles to execute method.

Comment: first i thought i'd go with spring security then i rode the part about row characteristics... I think that you should separate process in half : the part about group and user may be processed at application's level with spring security the part about row delegated to the DB